# WPF databind in memory image to Image control

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am using a DataGrid and trying to do the following Databinding

```
<DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Data.HeroCard1}">                                                
                                        </Image>                                            

                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
```

CustomImage is of type BitmapImage.  When I run I get the error:

Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject

The thing is that these images are stored as resources in a different assembly so I can't just point to a location on disk

Comment: Are you using a background thread to create the images?

Answer (score 1):

Ok after two hours of struggle I post here and immediately find the answer afterwards.  The problem is that I was creating the BitmapImages on another thread.  Even if the event that databinds is on the UI thread, it doesn't matter.  This is a little aggravating but I went ahead and changed my code to make sure images are only loaded from memory in the UI thread at all times and now it works well

Answer (score 0):

Make use of a [pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx).

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/PathToImages/MyImage.png"/>
```

Where AssemblyName, PathToImages, and MyImage.png are manipulated to fit your environment.